# Incorrect touchpad inputs, only scrolls up/down, strange mouse behavior

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, synaptics, macbook-pro, libinput

I am struggling to deal with strange behavior that started 'out of the blue', not after an update or anything.

**First**, the input to the touchpad is being incorrectly registered, and my touchpad scrolls all input as buttons or up/down scrolls:

```
[22:38] ~ $xinput test 16
motion a[2]=-451
button press   5
button release 5
motion a[2]=-452
button press   5
button release 5
motion a[1]=267 a[2]=-453
button press   5
button release 5
...
```

No taps are being made and all movement on the mouse pad only scrolls up or down, regardless of my actual movement. I can see this behavior even *before* logging in.

**Secondly**, with an external mouse, mouse movements are tracked correctly **UNTIL I TOUCH THE TOUCHPAD**, as soon as I try the touchpad, mouse clicks are no longer registered (for example, I cannot activate another application window with a mouse click, or access the dropdown menus with the mouse, or copy/paste text between applications).

All that I am able to do is navigate and switch applications using the keyboard (I know, not a bad thing in the end... but...).

My machine is a 2013 Macbook Pro. Here is some diagnostic information:

```
[22:29] ~ $uname -a
Linux macnix 4.6.3-040603-generic #201606241434 SMP Fri Jun 24 18:36:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[22:33] ~ $cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
```

and regarding xinputs:

```
[22:33] ~ $xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M705                             id=11   [slave pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K350                             id=12   [slave pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Wireless Bamboo PAD Pen stylus      id=13   [slave pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Wireless Bamboo PAD Finger touch    id=14   [slave pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad     id=16   [slave pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Wireless Bamboo PAD Pen eraser      id=17   [slave pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:0821)                    id=10   [slave keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad     id=15   [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Additionally, if I `dmesg | tail` I see the following:

```
[ 2364.471287] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 1, Code: 31, Value: 1
[ 2364.471293] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 0, Code: 0, Value: 0
[ 2364.631265] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 4, Code: 4, Value: 458774
[ 2364.631278] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 1, Code: 31, Value: 0
[ 2364.631283] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 0, Code: 0, Value: 0
[ 2366.739296] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 4, Code: 4, Value: 458792
[ 2366.739302] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 1, Code: 28, Value: 1
[ 2366.739306] evbug: Event. Dev: input21, Type: 0, Code: 0, Value: 0
```

I do not know what these are related to. I have looked at many of the similar problems and their solutions here at askubuntu, including the [modifications related to changing the /etc/default/grub file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux); [trying to replace xinput with libinput](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809034/16-04-elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-new-laptop?rq=1) but so far nothing has provided any solution. **Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!!!**

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but during the boot up, there is a message regarding "Failed to load kernel modules": https://gist.github.com/jfburkhart/1a4547201d3e15e629d46d96b58cbe96

Comment: I gave up! I installed 17.04 clean. My home directory is on a separate mount point, so it was relatively easy, but I switched from using touchegg to libinput-gestures in the process.