# 16.04.3 - Ubuntu does not register trackpad on HP 14-an013nr

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, hp-touchpad

I have installed ubuntu 17.04 and 16.04.3/16.04.2 on my new HP 14-an013nr laptop. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the trackpad working.

I have already reviewed the following question,
[16.04: Elantech touchpad not working on new laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809034/16-04-elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-new-laptop)

The poster's question differs from mine because he was able to use the trackpad even though it performed poorly. My system will not even show the trackpad as a piece of hardware.

I have reinstalled ubuntu over 7 times and tried everything I could find to no avail. It seems Ubuntu does not even recognize that the trackpad exists.

Does anyone have any ideas or know someone that has this working on Ubuntu? I have read articles where people describe the trackpad working fine on Arch Linux.

Thank you in advance! This laptop is really wonderful, it has a nice 14 inch 1080p monitor, decent specs, and is only $200! I would love to not have to carry around a mouse anymore...

Comment: Do you know the trackpad hardware is working and enabled in the BIOS? If you use the latest Ubuntu live from a USB stick does the trackpad work? Is there any sign of it in `lshw` or `lsusb`? Did you follow the advice in your link?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a kernel > 4.8.
To install a new kernel (e.g. 4.15), go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/
and download

linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_all.deb

linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb

linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb

Then run:
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb

Restart.

Comment: What evidence do you have that a kernel upgrade will fix this particular issue?