# Trackpad on my HP Laptop does not work at all

Tags: drivers, touchpad, hp

The trackpad worked during the installation proccess (booted via USB) and it also worked only once after that and that was it. When I do `xinput` this is what I get:

```
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HP HP Pavilion Gaming Mouse 200           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
```

Even after doing `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` which was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965952/16-04-3-ubuntu-does-not-register-trackpad-on-hp-14-an013nr) did not work after I typed `synaptics` I got this response:
`Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

Where can I find a solution or drivers?

*Note: I did not disable my trackpad because I do not have that function on my laptop*

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS