# Elantech touchpad not working in 18.04

Tags: touchpad, 18.04

I have an Elantech touchpad that is not working with Ubuntu 18.04. It doesn't recognize it at all, there's nothing about it in `xinput` and nothing coming up in `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` for example.

I've tried some of the solutions suggested for previous versions of Ubuntu, such as editing `/etc/default/grub` with `i8042.nomux=1` and `i8042.reset`. The patch suggested before won't work on the current kernel as well, so I'm at a loss...anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033033/elantech-touchpad-does-not-work-i2c-hid

Comment: Thanks, I looked in the BIOS but only stuff I found was related to low power use...tried toggling it for the touchpad but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these below steps:-

1. Install the package xserver-xorg-input-libinput
2. Uninstall xserver-xorg-input-evdev
3. Uninstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
4. Reboot and see if things work better.

got these steps from [16.04: Elantech touchpad not working on new laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809034/16-04-elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-new-laptop#809040) , and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by apt installing the linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04-edge and linux-image-extra-generic-hwe-18.04-edge packages.  These are metapackages that contain additional drivers.  This will result in installing kernel 5.0.0.  It may work with kernel 4.18.0 as well, but I haven't tried that so I can't verify that.  If you would rather try that, omit the "-edge" from these package names to install the version 4.18.0 packages.  I was also able to get it working using some of the kernel versions on ukuu, but I wouldn't recommend doing it that way as it is unsupported and could introduce other problems.